# Secure API with OpenID Connect - RP trust of OP

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Getting to grips with OpenID Connect with a third party IdP ( OP ) and securing APIs. I'm comfortable with the client and user agent component and the OAuth2.0 flows and scopes to get an access token and an id token issued to my client from an IdP

What I'm struggling with is the Resource Provider end and how the secured API trusts the access token that the client passes. I keep equating the trust element to SAML and the initial exchange of static configuration data between the IdP and the SP. That appears to be missing in OpenID Connect so I'm missing the trust element. I'm reading about dynamic discovery but again I'm missing a trick as to the trust between the RP and the IdP. What's to stop me setting up a rogue IdP ? Why should the API provider trust tokens coming from my IdP ?

Final question is on a local representation of the unique identifier in the RP. Does the account ID need to exist ahead of presentation of the access token ? I expect it does ( again using the SAML analogy which requires a local account representation ahead of authentication success ) so account management on the relying party is also a requirement for an end to end authentication to be successful.

Boils down to two questions. How does the API trust the access token presented ? Does the API provider need to have accounts provisioned ahead of successful authentication of those requests for resource ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Client Registration is used exactly in cases where there is no pre-established trust between parties and one wants to allow any OP that has a valid certificate to play.

When you want to restrict the set of OPs, you'd statically register with those in advance, thus doing the same type of bootstrapping to create pre-established trust as in SAML.

A unique identifier can be created by the (`<sub>`,`<iss>`) tuple as found in the `id_token` that the RP receives.

Comment: Thanks @Hans. Would you happen to have a reference to the process for static registrationin advance ? That makes the most sense in this use case. Native app or Single Page App that authenticates with an IDaaS ( Okta ) and makes use of several resource providers that expose their APIs and support OpenID Connect.

Comment: just like in SAML there's no defined way to do registration in advance: in essence it involves using some out-of-band channel to pass a client_id/client_secret and redirect_uri from RP to OP

Comment: Thanks @hans that fills in the gap. Much appreciated.

Comment: it would be nice if you could then accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic registration of the RP with the OP there is no trust metric described. There are two HTTP trust levels that can be enforced.

1. HTTPS is required with a certificate that chains up to the root of trust certs.
2. HTTPS has an EV certificate. This required in-proofing as defined by CAB.

I have proposed the use of a trust ecosystem in the IDESG, but that is some ways away.
It would be interesting to see if Kantara has any kind of solution in mind.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. So the resource provider in dymanic discovery is effectively an "authenticate with anyone" model as long as they support the protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

From an OpenID Connect perspective you are correct. That does not imply that any relying party code that you construct needs to be insecure. I mentioned two ways that you can verify the OP.

A similar set of security rules could be enforced by the OP, but as others have said, most OPs do not enable dynamic registration for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

The id_token is a JWS signed JWT. It is signed by an OpenID Connect OP (IdP), generally using its private key. You MUST verify the signature so that you're sure you know the JWT/id_token emitter. After that it's up to you to decide if you can trust this emitter for the action the client is willing to achieve.

The id_token contains a claim (at_hash) which is a reference to the access_token, so that you're sure the access token was generated by the same OP.